# Create a FileInputStream in a try-with-resources from different files based on a condition

Tags: java, fileinputstream, try-with-resources

I want to use try-with-resources with a condition. I want to create streams from file f1 if `OK == true`:

```
    try(FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(f1); FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(f1)) {...}
```

Or create the stream from file f2 if `OK == false`:

```
  try(FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(f2); FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(f2)) {...}
```

`OK` is a boolean value I have in my program.

Would it be possible to do this without introducing duplicate code and still keep the code reasonably easy to read? Or is there another solution that does the same thing without the try-with-resources?

Comments with some details about the solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a final `File` object outside the try block:

```
final File file = OK ? f1 : f2;

try(FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file)) {...}
```

Unless there's a reason to create two streams on the same file, the code should be as simple as `try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)){...}`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {...}` since OP says f1 if `OK` or f2 if not `OK`. So does OP want to evaluate OK to know which file to use?

Comment: @LuCio I also thought so, until I saw that he's creating 2 input streams on the same file... I don't know the reason, though (but that's a different thing altogether).

Comment: Yes .. I suppose this is how far OP managed to do it. But it's up to OP to clearify this.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to create 2 streams because I'm merging chunks of data from the files.